# Iterative Closest Point (ICP) overlapping ratio with open3d

Tags: python

I want to cacul the overlapping ratio between two point cloud. The idea is to create small equal box form the Aligned Bounding Box of the point cloud. Then calculate how much point there is in each small box. After this implementation for the two Differents Points Cloud, we compare all the same small box of the two Differents Points Cloud, then we make a ratio to have the overlaping ratio. My problem is to vizualize the sub boxes of each points clouds because i create them in a list since there is a lot of them. The Open 3d vizualizer problem is that i can't add a box on a curent vizualisation because it's in a list. Do you have an solution? I let you my code to try it.

Comment: import json
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
##initialisation of the parameter

source = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("C:/Users/sachx/Desktop/unniff/cloud_bin_0.pcd")

def main():
    ## Point Cloud creation
    points = np.asarray(source.points)
    point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    point_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)

    ## Create an Aligned Bounding Box for the all point cloud
    OBS = o3d.geometry.AxisAlignedBoundingBox.create_from_points(point_cloud.points)
    OBS.color=(1,0,0)# make the color red

Comment: # get the 8 points of this rectangular to create litle box in it
    X = o3d.geometry.AxisAlignedBoundingBox.get_box_points(OBS)
    print('X is the big box')
    print(np.asarray(X))



    #create a list for all the box and define the number of box
    list = []
    smallboxpoint=[]
    var = 5 #number of box for 1 size
    #lensource=len(source.points)

Comment: for k in range(var):
        for j in range(var):
            for i in range(var): start_position = [X[0][0]+i*((X[1][0]-X[0][0])/var), X[0][1]+j*((X[2][1]-X[0][1])/var), X[0][2]+k*((X[3][2]-X[0][2])/var)]
                cuboid_points = getCuboidPoints(start_position,X,var)
                pointss = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(cuboid_points)
                oriented_bounding_box = o3d.geometry.AxisAlignedBoundingBox.create_from_points(pointss)
                oriented_bounding_box.color = (1, 0, 1)
                list.append(oriented_bounding_box)

Comment: ## all box are now on a list but they have to be variable to be visualize

    a=list[0]
    b= list[1]
    cc = list[2]
    c = list[3]
    d = list[4]
    e = list[5]
    f = list[6]
    g = list[7]
    h = list[8]
    hg = list[9]
    i = list[10]
    j = list[11]
    jj = list[12]
    k = list[13]
    l = list[14]
    m = list[15]
    n = list[16]
    o = list[17]
    p = list[18]
    q = list[19]

Comment: o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([OBS,a,b,cc,c,d,e,f,g,h,hg,i,j,jj,k,l,m,n,o,p,q]
                                      , zoom=0.7,
                                      front=[0.5439, -0.2333, -0.8060],
                                      lookat=[2.4615, 2.1331, 1.338],
                                      up=[-0.1781, -0.9708, 0.1608])